# How can i make a popup with expire session

Tags: javascript, session

I have an image popup that appears on every page I navigate.

I need to know how is it possible to make it disappear if I click on close, it won't show up again for that session.

```
  <body onclick="document.getElementById('anuntImportant').style.display='none'">
      <div id="anuntImportant" style="position: absolute; top:30%;left:40%; display:block;overflow:visible; z-index:1000">
          <img src="image/data/program-sarbatori.jpg">
      </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sessionStorage for that:

```
function hide() {
  document.getElementById('anuntImportant').style.display='none';
  if (window.sessionStorage) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('hideAnuntImportant', true);
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  if (window.sessionStorage) {
    if (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('hideAnuntImportant'))) {
       document.getElementById('anuntImportant').style.display='none';
    }
  }
}

<body onclick="hide()">
```

or use php session, you will need to call ajax request on click and and in php call `start_session` and set `$_SESSION['anuntImportant']` to true and when you render the element you set `style="display: none"`

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
start_session();
$_SESSION['anuntImportant'] = true;
?>
```

**yourpage.php**

```
<?php 
start_session();
?>
  <body onclick="document.getElementById('anuntImportant').style.display='none'">
      <div id="anuntImportant" style="position: absolute; top:30%;left:40%; display:<?= $_SESSION['anuntImportant'] ? 'none' : 'block' ?>;overflow:visible; z-index:1000">
          <img src="image/data/program-sarbatori.jpg">
      </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: the first solutions it's ok, but it have a little delay, on a second page i navigate the popup is showing for 1 second and dissapear.

Comment: @Razvanhoratiu you will not have a delay if you use php. That's way I've included second solution.

Comment: i see it, but my opencart store page, don't allow that start_session on his page, and makes the page blank, is any solution for the first one with no delay?

Comment: it was a mistake the code from php is with session_start(); but is not showing anything...

Comment: @Razvanhoratiu Do you have anything before `<?php` in your file? You can't send anything before you run `start_session()` because it use cookies that need to be send in a header. Try adding: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` you should see php errors.